# Difference amplifier with potentiometer on input

Tags: operational-amplifier

I've wired this circuit :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAL5sz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When Vin- not connected to R1 I get Vin+ - Vin- in interval [0, 0.5]V when moving potentiometer
After, if I connect Vin- to R1 I get Vin+ - Vin- in interval [0, 1.8]V when moving potentiometer
Vout is in range [1, 3]V

Why does Vin- range change when I connect it to inverting input?

lah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because some current flows through R1, which "ruins" your voltage divider.

I.e. your voltage divider only works "properly" when negligible current flows through the wiper of the potentiometer. When R1 is disconnected, no current can flow, and the pot acts as a "proper" voltage divider. When you connect R1, a non-negligible current flows through R1, causing your voltage divider to "droop".